# How to do auto size groupbox?

Tags: c#, wpf

i have the grouping items from dictionary keypairs, its shown items in groupbox but its taken the groupbox height based on items.

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding MinorValues}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        IsItemsHost="True"
                        Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <GroupBox
                        MinWidth="405"
                        Margin="5,0,0,0">
                        <ItemsControl Margin="20,5,100,5">
                            <ItemsControl.Resources>
                                <CollectionViewSource x:Key="Collection" Source="{Binding Value}" />
                                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Model:AnalogOutput}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Label
                                            Grid.Column="1"
                                            Content="{Binding Name}"
                                            FontFamily="SegoeUI-Semibold"
                                            FontSize="12"
                                            FontWeight="SemiBold" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.Resources>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
                                <CompositeCollection>
                                    <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource Collection}}" />
                                </CompositeCollection>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </GroupBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Please see the below image,
           I want to show the items in groupbox like this based on items. 
[image]

Current Output:
[image]

Comment: Please share your valueable suggestion.